# how to print a particular value from an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i want to print first value of id 219 is mentioned in the screenshot for case:downloadl then i need to print 2nd value id=219 for case :downloadp.but,the array $value['printp'] getting both the values into the table(ex:Select usera Select userb).
           but i need to print only one and first value for this $value['printp']. [image]

```
case 'downloadl':


$sql = "SELECT post_id,printprocess,printsupply,printesb,printwork,printpri,printmate FROM printtable WHERE post_id=" .$post_id;

        $query = $db->sql_query($sql);
        $print_data = array();
        while($roww = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

                 $print_data[] = array(
                 'printp'   =>  $roww['printprocess'],
                 'prints'   =>  $roww['printsupply'],
                 'printsb'  =>  $roww['printesb'],
                 'printwrk' =>  $roww['printwork'],
                 'printpr'  =>  $roww['printpri'],
                 'printmat' =>  $roww['printmate'],
                 );
        }

              foreach($print_data as $value) {

                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, '');
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, '');
                    $j++;
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Printing Process');
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printp']);
                    $j++;
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Supplier');
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['prints']);
                    $j++;
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Espon Sub');
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printsb']);
                    $j++;
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'WorkFlow ID');
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printpr']);
                    $j++;
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Printer');
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printwrk']);
                    $j++;
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Printing Material');
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printmat']);
                    $i++;
                    $j++;
                }
 break;
              case:downloadp:

            foreach($print_data as $value) {

                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                                ->setCellValue('A'.$j, '');
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, '');
                            $j++;
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                                ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Printing Process');
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printp']);
                            $j++;
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                                ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Supplier');
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['prints']);
                            $j++;
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                                ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Espon Sub');
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printsb']);
                            $j++;
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                                ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'WorkFlow ID');
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printpr']);
                            $j++;
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                                ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Printer');
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printwrk']);
                            $j++;
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                                ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Printing Material');
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printmat']);
                            $i++;
                            $j++;
                        }
       break;
```

Comment: You have no `ORDER BY` in your query, so it's unpredictable which one will be first.

Comment: If you only want to print one row, get rid of the `while` loop.

Comment: i edited my question @Barmar can you please read that once again...!

Comment: First and second in what order? You need to use `ORDER BY` to get the results in a particular order.

Comment: @Barmar i want to print value (Selecta) for case:downloadl and (Selectb) for case:downloadp
but array $value['printp'] prints both (Selecta Selectb),so how can i print seperately without modifying query?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a column with a value specifically related to `downloadp` and `downloadi` that you can match in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: You're only doing the query in `case 'downloadl':`. Where does the other case get the `$print_data` array from?

Comment: i need to print (selecta) for first case then i want to print (selectb) for second case if (selectc) is present into same row i will write case 3 ..so i want to knlw how to print value seperately from an same array $value['printp']

Comment: There's no `selecta` or `selectb` in your data. Do you mean `Select UserA` and `Select UserB`?

Comment: sry my bad...i mentioned selecta and select instead of Select UserA and Select UserB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query in the different cases.

```
switch ($something) {
    case 'downloadl':
        $sql = "SELECT post_id,printprocess,printsupply,printesb,printwork,printpri,printmate FROM printtable WHERE post_id=" .$post_id . " AND printprocess = 'Select UserA'";
        break;
    case 'downloadp':
        $sql = "SELECT post_id,printprocess,printsupply,printesb,printwork,printpri,printmate FROM printtable WHERE post_id=" .$post_id . " AND printprocess = 'Select UserB'";
        break;
}

$query = $db->sql_query($sql);
$print_data = array();
while($roww = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    $print_data[] = array(
     'printp'   =>  $roww['printprocess'],
     'prints'   =>  $roww['printsupply'],
     'printsb'  =>  $roww['printesb'],
     'printwrk' =>  $roww['printwork'],
     'printpr'  =>  $roww['printpri'],
     'printmat' =>  $roww['printmate'],
     );
}

foreach($print_data as $value) {

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, '');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, '');
    $j++;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Printing Process');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printp']);
    $j++;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Supplier');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['prints']);
    $j++;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Espon Sub');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printsb']);
    $j++;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'WorkFlow ID');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printpr']);
    $j++;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Printer');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printwrk']);
    $j++;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$j, 'Printing Material');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $value['printmat']);
    $i++;
    $j++;
}
```

Comment: your case 2 should be `downloadp`

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Barmar but i want to print this printprocess  (Select UserA) dynamically because it may change any time when i change the database...may i use any array functions for this is it possible..???

Comment: @mrid ya downloadp is case2 i mentioned case2 instead of downloadp sry my mistake\

Comment: If it's dynamic, where does it come from? How do you know which one to choose for each case?

Comment: i getting it from my database...but i dont know how to print that seperately for each case...

Comment: My question is how do you know which value to print for each case? If `downloadl` is not always `Select UserA`, how do you know what it is?

Comment: You can use `if ($value['printp'] == "Select UserA")` but that's the same problem.

Comment: If you can explain the logic clearly, you should be able to translate that to code. The problem seems to be that you don't have a clear decription of what you want to do.

Comment: is there is any way to print based on index? i want to print first value for first case then second for second case like that...!

Comment: I've told you several times that you can't depend on the index unless you have an `ORDER BY` option in the query. The rows can be returned in any order, so sometimes `Select UserA` will be first, sometimes it will be second.

Comment: You can write `foreach ($print_data as $index => $value)`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: sry, i used orderby but it print first value for both the cases?

Comment: You can use `if ($index == 0)` or `if ($index == 1)` to get a particular index. You can also use `LIMIT 0, 1` and `LIMIT 1, 1` to make the query return just a particular row in the order.

Answer (score 1):

use **LIMIT 1**

```
SELECT post_id,printprocess,printsupply,printesb,printwork,printpri,printmate FROM printtable WHERE post_id=" .$post_id." LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `TOP 1` it uses `LIMIT 1`

Comment: He's changed the question. He wants a different row in the different `case` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT post_id,printprocess,printsupply,printesb,printwork,printpri,printmate FROM printtable WHERE post_id=" .$post_id . " ORDER BY pid LIMIT 1";
```

Here `ORDER BY post_id` will return you the output in increasing order (by default) of post_id

and `LIMIT 1` will limit the number of rows returned to 1.

Comment: He's only selecting one `post_id`, why do you need to order by that same column?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, my bad. Had to order by pid ( which appear to be the autogenerated primary key) rather than post_id. Updated my answer.

Comment: Have you seen the edit to the question? He wants the row with `Select UserA` in `case 'downloadl':` and the row with `Select UserB` in `case 'downloadp':`.

Comment: didn't see that, let me see

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is in the database,because your post_id is not an unique value,so you are pulling 2 or more values from the table. i would redesign the db, or you can use:

```
$sql = "SELECT post_id,printprocess,printsupply,printesb,printwork,printpri,printmate FROM printtable WHERE post_id=" .$post_id LIMIT 1;
```

to pull a single value from db, or remove the

```
foreach($print as $value)
```

from your code to print the first value.